# { "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." }

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So the problem I have already mentioned. I am a beginner, I might be doing some silly mistakes. So humble request to you guys to address my mistake and help me to complete my project. Thanks you all in advance.

**setting.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
}
```

this is the setting.py file and here I mention the required file

**view.py**

```
class LoginViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """ Check email and password and return auth token. """

    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
    permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))

    def create(self, request):
        """ Use ObtainAuthToken APIView to validate and create a token. """

        return ObtainAuthToken().post(request)
```

this is the view.py file.

**urls.py**

```
router.register('login', views.LoginViewSet, base_name="login")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('login/', ObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
    path(r'api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path(r'api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
]
```

**Error Message**
  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxa31.png)

Comment: Can you attach the code of your template, I feel like there may be an issue with your form.

Comment: Looks like you are sending a GET request to an endpoint that only accepts POST (and OPTIONS) requests. Using POST requests for an auth-related endpoint makes sense so I don't think there is anything wrong with the code here. Changing the request method probably solves the problem.

Comment: @Param actually i am using angular 6 as backend and i have got no response while logging in. Not even a error message. When click bttn nothing happens. And as far as i am concern i have no error from back end side.

Comment: @PashupatiPariyar  Your code here seems fine, as Fynn Becker said your auth form is sending a get request to the server, instead of a post request, so there has to a be a problem there, Django won't interfere with the client side 'form sending'.

Answer (score 0):

you must define `http_method_names` in DRF and specify your method access in your api.

```
class IndexViewAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head']
    # some statements
```